# AWS SAM set lambda resource based policy in serverless.template

Tags: aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have this template to deploy .net core web api to aws serverless. I want to set Resource-based policy of the lambda function (not api-gateway). For now the it auto generated with condition like this

```
"Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:region:accountid:id/*/*/*"
        }
      }
```

I just don't want it allow all

```
/*/*/*
```

and want to custom with my need.

serverless.template file

```
    {
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description": "",

  "Parameters": {
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": ""
    },
    "EnvironmentName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": ""
    }
  },
  "Globals":{
    "Api": {
        "BinaryMediaTypes": ["multipart/form-data"],
        "Cors": {
            "AllowMethods": "'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS'",
            "AllowHeaders": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,entity-context,user-context'",
            "AllowOrigin": "'*'",
            "AllowCredentials": "'true'"
        }
    }
  },
  "Resources": {

    "ACEApi": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {

        "FunctionName": "Api",
        "Handler": "ACE.Api.Aws.Serverless::Api.Aws.Serverless.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.1",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "MemorySize": 512,
        "Timeout": 60,
        "Environment" : {
            "Variables" : {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": { "Ref" : "EnvironmentName" }
            }
        },
        "Role": {
            "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
        },
        "Events": {
          "proxy": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "any"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  },
  "Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
      "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```